# Build OpenCV with CUDA

Tags: opencv, cuda

I am trying to build the openCV libraries with visual c++ 2008 express edition. I downloaded the latest code from the opencv svn server and used CMake 2.8 to create the projects. I installed the "CUDA Toolkit 32bit" and the "NPP library 32bit" in the default directory but everytime I try to build the libraries I always get the following error:

```
26>### Assertion failure at line 2135 of ../../be/cg/NVISA/cgtarget.cxx:
26>### Compiler Error in file C:/Users/[...]/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_00000ca4_00000000-19_surf.compute_20.cpp3.i during Code_Expansion phase:
26>### asm m constraint must have simple variable
26>nvopencc ERROR: C:/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v3.2/bin/../open64/lib//be.exe returned non-zero status 1
26>CMake Error at CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_generated_surf.cu.obj.cmake:256 (message):
26>  Error generating file
26>  B:/OCV/modules/gpu/Release/cuda_compile_generated_surf.cu.obj
26>Project : error PRJ0019: Ein Tool hat einen Fehlercode aus folgender Quelle zurückgegeben: "Building NVCC (Device) object modules/gpu/Release/cuda_compile_generated_surf.cu.obj"
26>Das Buildprotokoll wurde unter "file://b:\OCV\modules\gpu\opencv_gpu.dir\Release\BuildLog.htm" gespeichert.
26>opencv_gpu - 1 Fehler, 0 Warnung(en)
```

I am building the libraries on my Acer Aspire 5742g with the NVIDIA Geforce GT 540M and I don't know why it doesn't want to work. I already built the libraries in the same way on my PC with a GTX 280.

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug to me (assertion failure). Even if you do something wrong, the compiler should give you a meaningful error and not assert itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you follow this guide properly: [How to Build OpenCV 2.2 with GPU (CUDA) on Windows 7](http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/03/22/how-to-build-opencv-2-2-with-gpu-cuda-on-windows-7/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that expert on compiling  the latest versions of cuda 
The only thing I'm sure about is that cuda 4.0 support VS2010. 
Download Cuda tool kit 4.1 and to upgrade to VS2010.

S

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your PC supports NVIDIA graphics. Second, make sure that your cuda installation is correct.